# Change permalink in wp-property

Tags: permalinks, urls

I have set default property page so in the property url it shows /lima-investments/property-name. But I want to remove /lima-investments from the url.

I want to change following url

http://example.com/lima-investments/miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace/

to

http://example.com/miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace/

Please help.

Comment: Please help us identify 'lima-investments.' Is this a parent page, taxonomy, etc...?

Comment: lima-investment is a page. and miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace is a property(which is custom post type)

Comment: Are you using custom rewrites? Your comment doesn't quite make sense to me. If lima-investments is a page, out-of-the-box functionality would not then allow a custom post type to sit on top of that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [Custom permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin and it worked.